# "You didn't include a 'package.json' file in your source bundle..." while the file is there ? Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cicd

So we have 3 environments on this project and our dev and stg environment deployments work fine, but when I created a Beanstalk and went through the "eb init" and changing the gitab-ci.yml file I get the `Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'package.json' file in your source bundle. The deployment didn't install a specific Node.js version.` error and I just don't know what it wants from me. I hit `ls` on the runner commands and it obviously shows the package.json file in the root and it contains the defined Node version + it's exactly the same for dev and stg :O

All the envs are the same Node version, they all have the same setup, but for some reason it won't deploy to prod. Best thing about it is when I manually zip all the files and upload it via the console it all works fine so I don't know what to do. Any advice? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Were you able to resolve? I'm having a similar issue?